# RecyclerView duplicating items some time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

hey guys i m using recyclerview for displaying my images but their same time duplicate the vaule i am searching this problem on google i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323341/android-preventing-item-duplication-on-recyclerview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771302/recyclerview-items-duplicate-and-constantly-changing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497190/recycler-view-creating-duplicate-items) or more but no one is helping

**my code is**

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;
String PATH;
String link , img_txt;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;
String url1;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
File file1;
List<ImgModel> listmodel;
    public ImageAdapter(List<ImgModel> listmodel, Context context) {
    super();
    this.listmodel = listmodel;
    this.context = context;
    setHasStableIds(true);  //added  15/7/2016
}
   @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.img_row, parent, false);
     ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    ImgModel model = listmodel.get(position);
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(model.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.placeholder, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(model.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        link = listmodel.get(position).getImageUrl();
        img_txt = listmodel.get(position).getName();
        String fileExtension = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/"));
        Log.e("0_0","===>"+fileExtension);
        String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/myapp/";
         file1 = new File(dir+fileExtension);
        Log.d("file is ","longclick"+file1);
        if (file1.exists()) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(file1))));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, img_txt);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image with"));
        } else {
            new DownloadFile().execute(link);
        }
        return true;
    }
    });
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    url1 = listmodel.get(position).getImageUrl();
    Log.e("Hey Amit", "second is url" + url1);
    Imagefull();
    }
    });
    }
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return listmodel.size();
     }

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  public NetworkImageView imageView;
  public TextView textViewName;

  public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_img);
    textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_img);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }
}
```

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9E0V.png)

Comment: I think it is dislaying duplicate images when the images are not loading using their urls.

Comment: no its duplicating some time but that time urls also load i debug my code

Answer (score 3):

Change height  in your layout((R.layout.img_row) as wrap_content instead  of match_content

Comment: it stretching  my values

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might have heard that `setHasStableIds(true)` speeds up your recyclerviews but try either removing it or setting to false.

so simply try this:

```
setHasStableIds(false);
```

Then let me know what happens;

I had this issue and sometimes items were duplicated and sometimes never showed up at all and after removing that method call, it fixed my issues!

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: thank for reply but when it ture then its give sometime duplicate value but when its false its gives every time why

Comment: Just remove that method completely and see what happens; let me know

Answer (score 0):

Replace your above lines with below:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @Override
public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
    .inflate(R.layout.img_row, parent, false);
 ImageAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ImageAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

ImgModel model = listmodel.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()
    );
...........
..............
}

}
```